# Delphi: Draw a Arc in high resolution

Tags: delphi, canvas, vcl, delphi-2007

I need develop a circular progress bar in delphi 2007, I can't use third-party components (company policy). 
I'm using a Canvas, drawing an arc, that's works fine, but the image is at a very low resolution. It's possible to improve the resolution in canvas drawing?

Code sample:

```
procedure TForm1.DrawPieSlice(const Canvas: TCanvas; const Center: TPoint;
  const Radius: Integer; const StartDegrees, StopDegrees: Double);
 //Get it in http://delphidabbler.com/tips/148
const
  Offset = 90;
var
  X1, X2, X3, X4: Integer;
  Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4: Integer;
begin
  X1 := Center.X - Radius;
  Y1 := Center.Y - Radius;
  X2 := Center.X + Radius;
  Y2 := Center.Y + Radius;
  X4 := Center.X + Round(Radius * Cos(DegToRad(Offset + StartDegrees)));
  Y4 := Center.y - Round(Radius * Sin(DegToRad(Offset + StartDegrees)));
  X3 := Center.X + Round(Radius * Cos(DegToRad(Offset + StopDegrees)));
  Y3 := Center.y - Round(Radius * Sin(DegToRad(Offset + StopDegrees)));
  Canvas.Arc(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4);
end;

procedure TForm1.SpinEdit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  Center: TPoint;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  Radius: Integer;
  p: Pointer;
begin
  Label1.Caption:= SpinEdit1.Text+'%';
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.Width  := Image1.Width;
    Bitmap.Height := Image1.Height;
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
    Bitmap.HandleType :=  bmDIB;
    Bitmap.ignorepalette := true;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color   := clHighlight;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Pen.Width   := 10;
    Center := Point(Bitmap.Width div 2, Bitmap.Height div 2);
    Radius := 61;
    DrawPieSlice(Bitmap.Canvas, Center, Radius,0,round(SpinEdit1.Value * -3.6));

    Image1.Picture.Graphic := Bitmap;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Result:

[image: Sample]

I am open to proposals for other solutions.

Comment: The resolution is determined by you. If you want more resolution, make the circle bigger. If what you really mean is that you want anti aliasing then realistically you should switch to graphics32 or maybe gdi+. If your inane company policy prevents that, you'll have to learn how to write anti aliasing yourself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are not allowed to use any third-party graphic library with anti-aliasing possibilities, consider using GDI+, which is included in Windows, and Delphi has a wrapper for it.

```
uses
  ..., GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ, GDIPUTIL //included in Delphi standard modules

var
  graphics: TGPGraphics;
  SolidPen: TGPPen;
begin
  graphics := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
  graphics.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);
  SolidPen := TGPPen.Create(MakeColor(255, 0, 0, 255), 31);
  SolidPen.SetStartCap(LineCapRound);
  SolidPen.SetEndCap(LineCapRound);
  graphics.DrawArc(SolidPen, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 270);
  graphics.Free;
  SolidPen.Free;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if Direct2D units already exist in Delphi 2007, but it maybe a better option to use Direct2D since it is rendered using GPU, not CPU.

```
uses Vcl.Direct2D, Winapi.D2D1;

...

var
  D2DCanvas: TDirect2DCanvas;
begin
  if TDirect2DCanvas.Supported then
  begin
    D2DCanvas := TDirect2DCanvas.Create(PaintBox.Canvas, PaintBox.ClientRect);
    try
      D2DCanvas.RenderTarget.BeginDraw;
      D2DCanvas.RenderTarget.SetAntialiasMode(D2D1_ANTIALIAS_MODE_PER_PRIMITIVE);
      D2DCanvas.Pen.Color := TColors.Blue;
      D2DCanvas.Pen.Width := 10;
      D2DCanvas.Arc(100, 100, 200, 200, 100, 150, 150, 100);
      D2DCanvas.RenderTarget.EndDraw;
    finally
      D2DCanvas.Free;
    end;
  end
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

a very simple solution would be to draw your circle at a higher resolution (like 1.5x or 2x) on a temp bitmap and then resize it to your resolution (because the resize process will add antialias to your circle) and finally draw directly this bitmap to the canvas. in fact it's like this that many algorithm work to add antialias.

Comment: I don't think so. At least the standard delphi bitmap won't anti alias on resize. And I slowly don't believe that this would be an appropriate way to anti alias.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this does work if you call  SetStretchBltMode(DC, HALFTONE);

Comment: Not very well I think

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's subjective, here is sample that is done this way from one of my programs https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxRTkC3yy59rTUlfQVhyOUx2YW8

Comment: @David: actually, supersampling is a classic way to do antialiasing. It is not the fastest way, though.

Answer (score 0):

you may use the following unit (work in progress)
All you need to do is to add it to your "uses" and the supported TCanvas operations will be converted to GDI+
The "magic" is done by a TCanvas class helper that overrides the functions
supports: ellipse, polygon, polyline, lineTo, Arc, AngleArc

```
unit uAntiAliasedCanvas;

(*
Usage:
  Just include this unit in the "Uses" to turn AntiAliasing ON for the supported
  functions.

  use
    canvas.setAntiAliasing(boolean);
    to turn it off when needed

*)

interface
uses Graphics, types, UITypes, GdiPlus;

type TAntiAliasedCanvas = class helper for TCanvas
  private
    class var penPos : TPoint;
    function Graphics : IGPGraphics;
    function Pen : IGPPen;
    function Brush: IGPBrush;
    function path(const points : array of TPoint; close : boolean = false) : TGPGraphicsPath;
    function TGPcolorFromVCLColor(color : TColor) : TGPColor;
  private
    class var antiAliased : boolean;
  public
    procedure Ellipse(X1, Y1, X2, Y2: Integer);
    procedure Polyline(const Points: array of TPoint);
    procedure Polygon(const Points: array of TPoint);
    procedure lineTo(x,y : integer);
    procedure MoveTo(x,y : integer);
    procedure Arc(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4: Integer);
    procedure AngleArc(X, Y: Integer; Radius: Cardinal; StartAngle, SweepAngle: Single);
    class procedure setAntiAliasing(value : boolean);
end;

implementation

{ TAntiAliasedCanvas }

uses math, WinAPI.Windows, Direct2D, D2D1;


procedure TAntiAliasedCanvas.AngleArc(X, Y: Integer; radius: Cardinal;
  StartAngle, SweepAngle: Single);
begin
  if antiAliased then
    Graphics.DrawArc(pen, X-radius, Y-radius, radius*2, radius*2, -StartAngle, -SweepAngle)
  else
    inherited AngleArc(X, Y, Radius, StartAngle, SweepAngle)
end;


procedure TAntiAliasedCanvas.Arc(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4: Integer);
  var
    startAngle, toAngle, sweepAngle : single;
    R : TRect;
    C : TPoint;
begin
  if antiAliased then
    begin
      R := Rect(X1, Y1,x2,y2);
      R.NormalizeRect;
      C := R.CenterPoint;
      startAngle := math.RadToDeg(math.ArcTan2(y3-C.Y, X3-C.X));
      if startAngle < 0 then startAngle := startAngle + 360;
      toAngle := math.RadToDeg(math.ArcTan2(y4-C.Y, X4-C.X));
      if toAngle < 0 then toAngle := toAngle + 360;
      sweepAngle := -(toAngle - startAngle);
      if sweepAngle < 0 then sweepAngle := sweepAngle + 360;

      Graphics.DrawArc(pen,R.Left,R.Top, R.Width, R.Height, startAngle, -sweepAngle)
    end
  else
    inherited Arc(X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4)

end;

function TAntiAliasedCanvas.Brush: IGPBrush;
begin
  result := TGPSolidBrush.Create(
              TGPColor.Create(
                TGPcolorFromVCLColor(
                  (inherited brush).color)));
end;

procedure TAntiAliasedCanvas.Ellipse(X1, Y1, X2, Y2: Integer);
begin
  if antiAliased then
    begin
      if (inherited Brush).style <> bsClear then
        Graphics.fillEllipse(brush, X1, Y1, 1+X2-X1, 1+Y2-Y1);
      Graphics.drawEllipse(Pen, X1, Y1, 1+X2-X1, 1+Y2-Y1)
    end
  else
    inherited Ellipse(X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
end;

function TAntiAliasedCanvas.Graphics: IGPGraphics;
begin
  result := TGPGraphics.Create(Handle);
  result.SmoothingMode := SmoothingModeAntiAlias
end;

procedure TAntiAliasedCanvas.lineTo(x, y: integer);
begin
  if antiAliased then
  begin
    graphics.DrawLine(pen, penPos.X, penPos.Y, X, Y);
    moveTo(x,y)
  end
  else
    inherited lineTo(x,y)
end;

procedure TAntiAliasedCanvas.MoveTo(x, y: integer);
begin
  penPos.X := x;
  penPos.Y := y;
  inherited moveTo(x,y)
end;

function TAntiAliasedCanvas.path(const points: array of TPoint;
                                 close : boolean = false): TGPGraphicsPath;
  var
    GPPoints: array of TGPPointF;
    ptTypes : array of byte;
    i : integer;
begin
  assert(length(points)>0);
  setLength(GPPoints, length(points) + ord(close));
  setLength(ptTypes, length(points) + ord(close));
  for i := 0 to high(Points) + ord(close) do
    with points[i mod length(points)] do
      begin
        GPPoints[i] := TGPPointF.Create(x,y);
        ptTypes[i] := byte(PathPointTypeLine);
      end;
  result := TGPGraphicsPath.Create(GPPoints,ptTypes)
end;

function TAntiAliasedCanvas.pen: IGPpen;
begin
  result := TGPpen.Create(
              TGPColor.Create(
                TGPcolorFromVCLColor(
                  (inherited pen).color)),
              (inherited pen).width);
  case (inherited pen).style of
    psSolid        :  result.DashStyle :=  TGPDashStyle.DashStyleSolid;
    psDash         :  result.DashStyle :=  TGPDashStyle.DashStyleDash;
    psDot          :  result.DashStyle :=  TGPDashStyle.DashStyleDot;
    psDashDot      :  result.DashStyle :=  TGPDashStyle.DashStyleDashDot;
    psDashDotDot   :  result.DashStyle :=  TGPDashStyle.DashStyleDashDotDot;
  end;
  result.DashOffset
end;

procedure TAntiAliasedCanvas.Polygon(const Points: array of TPoint);
  var
    aPath : TGPGraphicsPath;
    aPen : IGPPen;
begin
  if length(points) = 0 then exit;

  if antiAliased then
    begin
      aPath := path(points, true);
      graphics.FillPath(brush, aPath);
      aPen := pen();
      aPen.SetLineJoin(LineJoinRound);
      graphics.DrawPath(aPen, aPath);
    end
  else
    inherited Polygon(points);
end;

procedure TAntiAliasedCanvas.Polyline(const Points: array of TPoint);
  var
    aPen : IGPPen;
begin
  if length(points) = 0 then exit;

  if antiAliased then
    begin
      aPen := pen();
      aPen.SetLineJoin(LineJoinRound);
      graphics.DrawPath(aPen, path(points))
    end
  else
    inherited polyline(points)
end;

class procedure TAntiAliasedCanvas.setAntiAliasing(value: boolean);
begin
  antiAliased := value
end;


function TAntiAliasedCanvas.TGPcolorFromVCLColor(color: TColor): TGPColor;
begin
    if Color < 0 then
      color := GetSysColor(Color and $000000FF);

    result := TGPColor.Create(
            color and $FF,
            (color and $FF00) shr 8,
            (color and $FF0000) shr 16)

end;

begin
  TCanvas.setAntiAliasing(true)
end.
```

Comment: Hi AnselmoMS - No. I have made almost no additional changes as all the TCanvas features I needed work well.
Please feel free to add features and make this a joint-venture :-)

Comment: Edited: Bug fix in "LineTo" thanks to @Сергей К

Comment: Edited: Added Arc, AngleArc